# iBatis dynamic select clause

Tags: java, ibatis

I've a requirement to generate select criteria dynamically from java end and pass it to ibatis and it works well this way 
`select $runtime$ from .... (runtime is being generated in a java class)` 
but as `$runtime$` causes sql injection , I'm looking for ways to use `#runtime#` instead of `$`.

**Note** : `#runtime#` is putting the value as prepared statement and the query prints it as it is instead of using it as a select clause

```
runtime = 'sysdate';
select $runtime$ from dual -> select sysdate from dual -> 16-Jun-2014 ....
select #runtime# from dual -> select 'sysdate' from dual -> sysdate
```